# Pyspark dataframe filter for exploded column

Tags: dataframe, filter, pyspark, aws-glue

Would like to filter rows based on the value of a column.

```
 df = dataSource0.toDF();
 transDf = df.withColumn("daily_qty", F.split(F.concat_ws(',',*(x for x in sorted(df.columns) if  x.startswith('daily_qty_'))),',')) 
 ds2=transDf.withColumn("start_date",F.col("startdt_for_dailyqty")).withColumn("end_date",F.date_add(F.col("startdt_for_dailyqty"),48))         
 ds4 = ds2.withColumn("lineoffdate", F.expr("""sequence(start_date,end_date,interval 1 day)""")).withColumn("temp",F.arrays_zip("daily_qty","lineoffdate")).withColumn("temp",F.explode("temp"))))
 ds4.select("part_no","prod_week","temp.daily_qty","temp.lineoffdate").show()
 ds4.printSchema()
 **ds4.filter(F.col('temp.daily_qty') != '000000000')**
 print("after filter** " ,ds4.count())
```

Filter does not work for this field alone. For the other field it works. I tried array_contains in the filter for daily_qty. It did not work for that as well. What am I missing here. 
Sample data below

```
+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
|     part_no|prod_week| daily_qty|lineoffdate|
+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
|019990616100|   202004| 000000000| 2020-01-23|
|019990616100|   202004| 000000000| 2020-01-24|
|019990616100|   202004| 000000000| 2020-01-25|
|019990616100|   202005| 000000001| 2020-01-26|
+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

Trying to explode two columns and filter is not working for the exploded column.

Comment: you are not assigning `ds4.filter(F.col('temp.daily_qty') != '000000000')` to anything. may be `ds5 = ds4.filter(F.col('temp.daily_qty') != '000000000')` and `ds5.show()` ?

Comment: It does not work that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data in 'daily_qty' column is prefixed with a white space character.

Comment: I don't think so. How do you say that?

Comment: Look at your show(). First char in column is a space. Unless of course your column name is prefixed with a space.

Comment: Try adding a whitespace character to your filter and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Did you find the problem?